# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience - warning

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am getting this warning and I am not aware what to do.

**js code:**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

subBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var crd = document.createElement("div");
    crd.setAttribute("class", "card");
    crd.innerHTML = inptTxt.value;
    contDiv .appendChild(crd);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("card").bgColor = JSON.parse(this.responseText).color;          
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor","" ,true);
    xhttp.send(); 
})
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There's a stray `,""` argument in your `open()` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the open line to

```
xhttp.open("GET","http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor",true);
```